# how to combine rows in a data frame by id

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame:

```
+---------+---------------------+                                                 
|       id|                 Name|
+---------+---------------------+
|        1|               'Gary'|
|        1|              'Danny'|
|        2|        'Christopher'|
|        2|              'Kevin'|
+---------+---------------------+
```

I need to combine all the Name values in the id column. Please tell me how to get from it:

```
+---------+------------------------+                                                 
|       id|                    Name|
+---------+------------------------+
|        1|       ['Gary', 'Danny']|
|        2| ['Kevin','Christopher']|
+---------+------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use groupBy and collect functions. Based on your need you can use list or set etc.

```
df.groupBy(col("id")).agg(collect_list(col("Name"))
```

in case you want duplicate values

```
df.groupBy(col("id")).agg(collect_set(col("Name"))
```

if you want unique values

Answer (score 2):

Use **`groupBy`** and **`collect_list`** functions for this case.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df.groupBy(col("id")).agg(collect_list(col("Name")).alias("Name")).show(10,False)

#+---+------------------------+
#|id |Name                    |
#+---+------------------------+
#|1  |['Gary', 'Danny']       |
#|2  |['Kevin', 'Christopher']|
#+---+------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby('id')['Name'].apply(list)
```